# For Matlab, Import data from xlsx, how to get 1st row as variable name, and rest of the column as data for variable name

Tags: matlab, import, xlsx

In my excel file. The very first row in each column is a string.  The rest of the column is data for that string, i.e

```
'time' 
1
2
3
4
```

I want to take the first row in excel, and make that the variable name in Matlab, and the rest of the column data is numerical data for that variable.  So in Matlab, time would be a column vector of numbers 1, 2 ,3 ,4.

I can't get this to work.

Comment: I don't have access to MATLAB right now, but I'm fairly sure that the Import Wizard has a checkbox for that. Have you looked at that wizard?

Comment: do you mean the help button?

Comment: Dynamic variable names are not recommended. It is much better to use structures. Check out [Loren's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) about dynamic field references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
[val nms] = xlsread( xlsFileName );
assert( size(val,2) == size(nms,2), 'mismatch number of columns and number of names');
for ci=1:size(val,2)
    eval( [ nms{ci}, ' = val(:,ci);' ] ); % name the column
end
```

What makes this work:

1. This code calls `xlsread` with **two** output variables. This way `xlsread` puts the numeric data into the first variable, and text data into the second. See [`xlsread` doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) for more info.
2. Using `eval` to assign values to variable (`time`) which name is stored in another variable (`nms{1}`). The argument of the `eval` commands is a **string** `time = val(:,1);`, which the Matlab command that assigns the values of the first column of data (`val(:,1)`) to a new variable named `time`.

Comment: ??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in ==> Andre_alg at 8
    eval ([ndata{ci}, ' = ndata(:,ci);']);

Comment: When you try this code, what are the types of `val` and `nms`? They are supposed to be `double` for `val` and `cell` for `nms`. Make sure your excel file has a single sheet with text **only** at the top row

Comment: actually val is the column numerical data, and nms is the string in the first row.  for nms I received 43 columns of string names for each column. I kinda wanted each string name to be a variable that holds the column numerical data of val. idk if that makes sense. thanks again

Comment: Have you tried out my code? you need to have **two** outputs for `xlsread` for it to work. It seems like you are working with only one output `ndata`. If you have in your excel file columns with title without value, then you'll need to make adjustments to my code. But the basics remain.

Comment: actually I did get columns of data also. still get that error though. hmm gotta see why. thanks

Comment: please see my edited expanded answer. This should help you debug your error.

Comment: thanks that will help a lot. did i mention it is many columns with the first row as a string name. below each string are columns of numerical data

Comment: as long as each column has both text header (first row) and numerical values beneath it - my code should be able to process it. Note that the code assumes the header of each column represent a **legitimate** variable name. If the title is not a legitimate variable name (e.g., "1time") then the code will exit with an error.

Comment: what if the text header , each row is a string with '' in excel. for example in excel, the row for time, is written as 'time' and written with just the words time

Comment: You'll have to try it out and see what strings you get in `nms` variable. However, this code works for me on a small excel file with two columns ("time" and "val") and four rows of numeric data.